# Validating a child input type file with react-hook-form and Yup

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup, react-functional-component

I'm creating a form with a file upload with help of `react-hook-form` and `Yup`. I am trying to use the register method in my child component. When passing register as a prop (destructured in curly braces) the validation and submiting doesn't work. You can always submit the form and the submitted file object is empty.
Here's a sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-dijkstra-8htjk?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several of problems with your code.

1- `register` method returns an object with these properties:

```
{
  onChange: function(){},
  onBlur:function{},
  ref: function(){}
 }
```

when you define your input like this:

```
<input
      {...register('photo')}
      ...
      onChange={(event) => /*something*/}
  />
```

actually you are overrding the `onChange` method which has returned from `register` method and react-hook-form couldn't recognize the field change event. The solution to have your own `onChange` alongside with `react-hook-form`'s `onChange` could be something like this:

```
const MyComp = ()=> {
  const {onChange, ...registerParams} = register('photo');
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <input
        {...params}
        ...
        onChange={(event) => {
          // do whatever you want
          onChange(event)
        }}
      />
  );
}
```

2- When you delete the photo, you are just updating your local state, and you don't update `photo` field, so `react-hook-form` doesn't realize any change in your local state.

the problems in your `ImageOne` component could be solved by change it like this:

```
function ImageOne({ register, errors }) {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
  const { onChange, ...params } = register("photo");
  return (
    ...
    <Button
           className="delete"
           onClick={() => {
              setSelectedImage(null);
              //Make react-hook-form aware of changing photo state
              onChange({ target: { name: "photo", value: [] } });
            }}
          >
         ...
          <input
            //name="photo"
            {...params}
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            id="single"
            onChange={(event) => {
              setSelectedImage(event.target.files[0]);
              onChange(event); // calling onChange returned from register 
            }}
          />
       ...
  );
}
```

3- Since your input type is `file` so, the value of your `photo` field has `length` property that you can use it to handle your validation like this:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  photo: yup
    .mixed()
    .test("required", "photo is required", value => value.length > 0)
    .test("fileSize", "File Size is too large", (value) => {
      return value.length && value[0].size <= 5242880;
    })
    .test("fileType", "Unsupported File Format", (value) =>{
      return value.length && ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpg"].includes(value[0].type)
    }
    )
});
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-waterfall-cqyz4?file=/src/App.js) is the full edited version of your file.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I knew about the other problems with the code but I wanted to figure out why the submitted object was empty first. You helped me with both of the issues though, so once again - huge thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.